# failed_when do not work with telnet output

Tags: ansible

I will try to set a telnet task to failed if "instance" is in the output message, but it didn't work.

here is the log:

```
TASK [ISAM Log to log1 and log2] **************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/sascha.mueller/Downloads/isam_log.yml:9
changed: [1.2.3.4] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "failed_when_result": false, 
    "output": [
        "configure system syslog no route dslamlog msg-type all\r\n\r\nError : instance does not exist\r\n\r\nISAM-ISAM_7363_Labor_Zw>#", 
        "configure system syslog no destination dslamlog\r\n\r\nError : instance does not exist\r\n\r\nISAM-ISAM_7363_Labor_Zw>#"
    ]
}

TASK [fail the play if the previous command did not succeed] **********************************************************************************************************
task path: /Users/sascha.mueller/Downloads/isam_log.yml:27
skipping: [1.2.3.4] => {
    "changed": false, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
```

I also tried command_output.stderr e.g. but all these values doesn't exist

```
---
-
 hosts: all
 connection: local
 become: no

 tasks:
 - name: ISAM Log to log1 and log2
   ignore_unreachable: yes
   telnet:
     user: bla
     password: blubb
     login_prompt: "login: "
     password_prompt: "password: "
     timeout: 5
     prompts:
       - "[#|$]"
     command:
       - configure system syslog no route dslamlog msg-type all
       - configure system syslog no destination dslamlog

   register: command_output
     failed_when: "'instance' in command_output.output"


 - name: fail the play if the previous command did not succeed
   fail:
     msg: "the command failed"
   when: "'instance' in command_output.output"
```

Is it possible to check this with an telnet command or to direct check it with variable.output or only with variable.stderr?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in your example that `output` is a **list**:

```
"output": [
    "configure system syslog no route dslamlog msg-type all\r\n\r\nError : instance does not exist\r\n\r\nISAM-ISAM_7363_Labor_Zw>#", 
    "configure system syslog no destination dslamlog\r\n\r\nError : instance does not exist\r\n\r\nISAM-ISAM_7363_Labor_Zw>#"
]
```

When you ask if `"'instance' in command_output.output"`, you are asking if there is an *item* in `outout` that is the string `instance`.  That is, your expression would evaluate to true if `output` looked like this:

```
"output": [
    "this item does not match",
    "instance"
]
```

What you really want to ask is "does any item in `output` contain the string `instance`?".  The simplest way to do that is probably by concatenating all the lines into a single string:

```
"'instance' in ''.join(command_output.output)"
```

You should be able to use this in either you `failed_when` condition:

```
- name: ISAM Log to log1 and log2
  ignore_unreachable: yes
  telnet:
    user: bla
    password: blubb
    login_prompt: "login: "
    password_prompt: "password: "
    timeout: 5
    prompts:
      - "[#|$]"
    command:
      - configure system syslog no route dslamlog msg-type all
      - configure system syslog no destination dslamlog

  register: command_output
  failed_when: "'instance' in ''.join(command_output.output)"
```

Or in the `when` statement on your `fail` task:

```
 - name: fail the play if the previous command did not succeed
   fail:
     msg: "the command failed"
   when: "'instance' in ''.join(command_output.output)"
```